# ruby - Enumerable example - confused

Tags: ruby

I am new to ruby. I am confused about Enumerable examples.

```
a = %w(albatross dog horse)  
a.max    #Answer: "horse"   --why horse?
a.max(2) #Answer: ["horse", "dog"] --why horse,dog?
```

Please explain.

Comment: What are you confused about? What result did you expect?

Comment: Make at least 8 items and second by maximum should be the last one - and you will find a bug :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The alphabetical order is:

1. **a**lbatross
2. **d**og
3. **h**orse

[`max`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-max) returns these in descending order (i.e. starting with the *maximum* value):

```
a.max    #=> "horse"
a.max(1) #=> ["horse"]
a.max(2) #=> ["horse", "dog"]
a.max(3) #=> ["horse", "dog", "albatross"]
```

[`min`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-min) does the opposite (i.e. starting with the *minimum* value):

```
a.min    #=> "albatross"
a.min(1) #=> ["albatross"]
a.min(2) #=> ["albatross", "dog"]
a.min(3) #=> ["albatross", "dog", "horse"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `h` comes after `d`, which comes after `a` in ASCII code.

Comment: Thanks. I thought max mean which word contain more letters :)

Comment: @Khoga the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-max) contains another example: `a.max(2) {|a, b| a.length <=> b.length } #=> ["albatross", "horse"]`

Answer (score 0):

Here's why:

`"a" > "b"  #=> false`

and

`"a" < "b" # => true`

The characters with a higher value in ASCII (and therefore alphabet) have a higher value in Ruby. Pass `n` to the `max` method and you'll receive `n` elements of the array with the highest values.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the [max](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-max) method of enumerable compares object using the `<=>` operator, which is used by the [comparable mixin](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Comparable.html) to compare object together, in your case, you have a Enumerable of String, and string include the `comparable` and hence rewrite the `<=>` operator, which is the alphabetical order, see:

```
puts 'albatross' <=> 'horse' # -1 
puts 'albatross' <=> 'dog' # -1
puts 'horse' <=> 'dog' # 1
```

If the first string is before the second one in the alphabetical order, then the method return -1, otherwise the method return 1 (or 0 if string are equals).

Hope it helps